# how do i call python script with passing localStorage variable and html newpage on same radio button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, python-2.7

So my requirement is, if i checked the any of the radio button.My HTML should call the  both python script with passing the sessionstorage or localstorage variable[FullurlName] and also call the next html page(with that same radio button click).

Note:- You can give answers in javascript or jquery or ajax or any which possible with html.

Immediate assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >


  var url_name = localStorage.getItem("urlName");
var site_name = localStorage.getItem("siteName");
var url_cmmd;
<!--
if (site_name == 'site1') {
  url_cmmd = "scrapy crawl site1_spider -a inputDetailUrl='" + url_name + "' -o site1_output.";
} else if (site_name == 'site2') {
  url_cmmd = "scrapy crawl site2_spider -a inputDetailUrl='" + url_name + "' -o site2_output.";
} else if (site_name == 'site3') {
  url_cmmd = "scrapy crawl site3_spider -a inputDetailUrl='" + url_name + "' -o site3_output.";
} else if (site_name == 'site4') {
  url_cmmd = "scrapy crawl site4_spider -a inputDetailUrl='" + url_name + "' -o site4_output.";
} else if (site_name == 'site5') {
  url_cmmd = "scrapy crawl site5_spider -a inputDetailUrl='" + url_name + "' -o site5_output.";
}
//-->


function file_form_func() {

  var file_format
  if (document.getElementById('f-option').checked) {
    file_format = document.getElementById('f-option').value;
  } else if (document.getElementById('s-option').checked) {
    file_format = document.getElementById('s-option').value;
  } else if (document.getElementById('t-option').checked) {
    file_format = document.getElementById('t-option').value;
  }
  sessionStorage.setItem("FullurlName", url_cmmd + file_format);
  window.location.href = 'loading_Textfly.html'
} <
/script>
```

```css
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato');
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  background: #222222;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  height: 450px;
  width: 400px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h2 {
  color: #AAAAAA;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.container ul {
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  color: #AAAAAA;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #111111;
}

ul li input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

ul li label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.35em;
  padding: 25px 25px 25px 80px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  height: 30px;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
}

ul li:hover label {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul li .check {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid #AAAAAA;
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  top: 30px;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 5;
  transition: border .25s linear;
  -webkit-transition: border .25s linear;
}

ul li:hover .check {
  border: 5px solid #FFFFFF;
}

ul li .check::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  margin: auto;
  transition: background 0.25s linear;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.25s linear;
}

input[type=radio]:checked~.check {
  border: 5px solid #0DFF92;
}

input[type=radio]:checked~.check::before {
  background: #0DFF92;
}

input[type=radio]:checked~label {
  color: #0DFF92;
}

.signature {
  position: fixed;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  top: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.signature p {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  color: #AAAAAA;
}

.signature .much-heart {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 4px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: #AC1D3F;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.signature .much-heart::before,
.signature .much-heart::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #AC1D3F;
  top: -4px;
}

.signature .much-heart::after {
  bottom: 0;
  top: auto;
  left: -4px;
}

.signature a {
  color: #AAAAAA;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" onclick="">

  <h2>Download type:</h2>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="f-option" name="selector" value="csv" onclick='file_form_func()'>
      <label for="f-option">CSV</label>

      <div class="check"></div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="s-option" name="selector" value="json" onclick='file_form_func()'>
      <label for="s-option">JSON</label>

      <div class="check">
        <div class="inside"></div>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <input type="radio" id="t-option" name="selector" value="xml" onclick='file_form_func()'>
      <label for="t-option">XML</label>

      <div class="check">
        <div class="inside"></div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what do you want to achieve?
With one mouse click perform two (possibly contradictory) actions like executing javascript function (which can load another page) AND loading another page (but not using for this the called javascript)?

Comment: What have you tried yourself to achieve your requirement and why didn't it work?

Comment: Actually, i tried to pass local storage variable to python script which i formed [FullurlName], but i surfed in google many of the answers were calling the script alone but not passing the parameters or arguments to the script. Even i can change the calling of next page to another button also , that's not a problem. Now i really need is to call the python script and also pass variable to the function of the script.

Comment: Is modifying the python script code adding to it "varName = 'parameter'" or ("exec("functionName('param1', 'param2') ") before it is written to local storage the solution you look for?
By the way: HOW have you tired to pass local storage variable to the script?